# Conceptual difference between "Trash Can" and "Recycle Bin"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference

Is there a conceptual difference between a trash can and a recycle bin in English (such as the recycle bin being for things that shall or can be recycled while a trash can is only for pure garbage)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you provided the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

"Trash can" is a mainly North American term for a receptacle or container for waste. 'Rubbish bin' is a mainly British term for these things. Otherwise you have it right.